# How to add newline for the file/directory name in Nautilus?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, filename

I am trying to do this
[image]

A and B are in different lines

I know how to do it in terminal.

```
mkdir 'A'$'\n''B'
```

How to do it in Nautilus?

Comment: I would strongly recommend not to put line breaks in any file or directory names, as many not 100% safely written scripts and applications might break and show unexpected behaviour on these.